# What do I need to do to get my code to show an image in a modal?

Tags: angularjs

I'm iterating over an Images model and I want to be able to click on the image name and show the image in a modal.

Using this existing code how would I achieve this?  This code is working for other urls so if I pass `/contact` into the `openPopup` function it will show the correct page.

The images are coming from a separate domain, so not on the same server.

```
 <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel" data-popup>
     @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
     {
      <span ng-click="openPopup('http://url/to/image.jpg')">@image.Name</span><br />
                    <div>
                        <span>@image.Name</span>
                        <img src="@image.ImageUrl" alt="" />
                    </div>
      }
  </div>


.directive('modal',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        transclude:true,
        scope:true,
        templateUrl:'modal.tpl.html'

    }
})


.directive('popup',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        scope:true,
        controller:
        ['$scope','$modal',
        function($scope,$modal){
            $scope.openPopup=function(url){
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl:url
                })
            }

        }]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this by changing this:

```
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl:url
            })
```

to this:

```
            $modal.open({
                template: '<div>inline modal content</div>'
            })
```